# Verifying if the user is owner of the email address in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying user Authentication using firebase.

For Email and password based authentication, I want to check whether the email input by the user in the form really belongs to the user, I can do so by sending a verification link to the user.

So, after the form is submitted and all other validation are complete, i tried the following code:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email,this.state.password)
        .then(()=>{
            var actionCodesettings={
                url: 'https://localhost:3000/?email=' + firebase.auth().currentUser.email,
                handleCodeInApp: false
            }
            firebase.auth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification(actionCodesettings)
             .then(()=>{
               console.log("Email Sent")
             })
             .catch((error)=>{
                 console.log("Unexpected error occured")
             })

        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            var errorCode = error.code;
            if(errorCode === 'auth/email-already-in-use'){
                this.setState({
                    Message:"Email already Used"
                })
                return;
            }
            else if(errorCode === 'auth/invalid-email'){
                this.setState({
                    Message:"Email already Used"
                })
            return;
            }
            else if(errorCode === 'auth/weak-password'){
                this.setState({
                    Message:"Password is too Weak"
                })
            return;
            }
        })
    }
```

But I am not recieving any email,neither the message "Email Sent" is logged out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a syntax error because you have used `firebase.auth.currentUser`  instead of `firebase.auth().currentUser`.

The reason you don't see this error is because you are ignoring it by not handling error codes that you don't expect. A good way to pick up on these types of bugs is to use a `switch` statement with a `default` fallback case.

```js
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email,this.state.password)
    .then((result) => {
        var actionCodesettings={
            url: 'https://localhost:3000/?email=' + result.user.email,
            handleCodeInApp: false
        }
        return result.user
            .sendEmailVerification(actionCodesettings);
    })
    .then(() => {
        this.setState({
            Message:"Please check your email to verify it."
        });
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        const errorCode = error.code;
        switch (errorCode) {
            case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
                this.setState({
                    Message:"This email has already been used"
                });
                return;
            case 'auth/invalid-email':
                this.setState({
                    Message:"Email was invalid"
                });
                return;
            case 'auth/weak-password':
                this.setState({
                    Message:"Please use a more secure password"
                });
                return;
            default:
                console.error("Unexpected code while signing in and verifying user", error);
                this.setState({
                    Message:"Unexpected error. Please contact support."
                });
                return;
        }
    });
```